# rmagick "installs" and is unable to find contents of gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, osx-lion, rmagick

A bit of a noobie here, sorry if this has already been addressed but I can't find this one anywhere yet.

Using OSX 10.7 with Jewelry Box, Ruby 1.8 and Rails 3.

Spending several hours going through fixes found on other sites and SO, I have gone forward and backwards trying to get a bundle to install that wont get past rmagick. I've solved the issue where magickwand.h wasn't being found in the right location only to find out it gets better.

```
Elliott:trunk jitscaleusa$ sudo gem install rmagick
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed rmagick-2.13.2
Installing ri documentation for rmagick-2.13.2

No definition for Magick_colors

No definition for Magick_fonts

No definition for Magick_init_formats

No definition for Magick_limit_resource

No definition for Magick_set_cache_threshold

No definition for Magick_set_log_event_mask

No definition for Magick_set_log_format

No definition for Image_initialize

No definition for Image_combine

No definition for Image_constitute

No definition for Image__load

No definition for Image_capture

No definition for Image_ping

No definition for Image_read

No definition for Image_read_inline

No definition for Image_from_blob

No definition for Image_adaptive_blur

No definition for Image_adaptive_blur_channel

No definition for Image_adaptive_resize

No definition for Image_adaptive_sharpen

No definition for Image_adaptive_sharpen_channel

No definition for Image_adaptive_threshold

No definition for Image_add_compose_mask

No definition for Image_add_noise

No definition for Image_add_noise_channel

No definition for Image_add_profile

No definition for Image_affine_transform

No definition for Image_remap

No definition for Image_alpha

No definition for Image_alpha_q

No definition for Image_aref

No definition for Image_aset

No definition for Image_auto_gamma_channel

No definition for Image_auto_level_channel

No definition for Image_auto_orient

No definition for Image_auto_orient_bang

No definition for Image_properties

No definition for Image_bilevel_channel

No definition for Image_black_threshold

No definition for Image_blend

No definition for Image_blue_shift

No definition for Image_blur_image

No definition for Image_blur_channel

No definition for Image_border

No definition for Image_border_bang

No definition for Image_change_geometry

No definition for Image_change_geometry

No definition for Image_changed_q

No definition for Image_channel

No definition for Image_compare_channel

No definition for Image_check_destroyed

No definition for Image_compare_channel

No definition for Image_channel_depth

No definition for Image_channel_extrema

No definition for Image_channel_mean

No definition for Image_charcoal

No definition for Image_chop

No definition for Image_clut_channel

No definition for Image_clone

No definition for Image_color_flood_fill

No definition for Image_color_histogram

No definition for Image_colorize

No definition for Image_colormap

No definition for Image_composite

No definition for Image_composite_bang

No definition for Image_composite_affine

No definition for Image_composite_channel

No definition for Image_composite_channel_bang

No definition for Image_composite_mathematics

No definition for Image_composite_tiled

No definition for Image_composite_tiled_bang

No definition for Image_compress_colormap_bang

No definition for Image_contrast

No definition for Image_contrast_stretch_channel

No definition for Image_convolve

No definition for Image_convolve_channel

No definition for Image_copy

No definition for Image_crop

No definition for Image_crop_bang

No definition for Image_cycle_colormap

No definition for Image_decipher

No definition for Image_define

No definition for Image_deskew

No definition for Image_delete_compose_mask

No definition for Image_delete_profile

No definition for Image_despeckle

No definition for Image_destroy_bang

No definition for Image_destroyed_q

No definition for Image_difference

No definition for Image_dispatch

No definition for Image_displace

No definition for Image_display

No definition for Image_dissolve

No definition for Image_distort

No definition for Image_distortion_channel

No definition for Image__dump

No definition for Image_dup

No definition for Image_each_profile

No definition for Image_edge

No definition for Image_emboss

No definition for Image_encipher

No definition for Image_enhance

No definition for Image_equalize

No definition for Image_equalize_channel

No definition for Image_erase_bang

No definition for Image_excerpt

No definition for Image_excerpt_bang

No definition for Image_export_pixels

No definition for Image_export_pixels_to_str

No definition for Image_extent

No definition for Image_find_similar_region

No definition for Image_flip

No definition for Image_flip_bang

No definition for Image_flop

No definition for Image_flop_bang

No definition for Image_frame

No definition for Image_function_channel

No definition for Image_gamma_channel

No definition for Image_gamma_correct

No definition for Image_gaussian_blur

No definition for Image_gaussian_blur_channel

No definition for Image_get_pixels

No definition for Image_gray_q

No definition for Image_gray_q

No definition for Image_histogram_q

No definition for Image_implode

No definition for Image_import_pixels

No definition for Image_init_copy

No definition for Image_inspect

No definition for Image_level2

No definition for Image_level_channel

No definition for Image_level_colors

No definition for Image_levelize_channel

No definition for Image_linear_stretch

No definition for Image_liquid_rescale

No definition for Image_magnify

No definition for Image_magnify_bang

No definition for Image_map

No definition for Image_marshal_dump

No definition for Image_marshal_load

No definition for Image_mask

No definition for Image_matte_flood_fill

No definition for Image_median_filter

No definition for Image_minify

No definition for Image_minify_bang

No definition for Image_modulate

No definition for Image_monochrome_q

No definition for Image_motion_blur

No definition for Image_negate

No definition for Image_negate_channel

No definition for Image_normalize

No definition for Image_normalize_channel

No definition for Image_oil_paint

No definition for Image_opaque

No definition for Image_opaque_channel

No definition for Image_opaque_q

No definition for Image_ordered_dither

No definition for Image_paint_transparent

No definition for Image_palette_q

No definition for Image_pixel_color

No definition for Image_polaroid

No definition for Image_posterize

No definition for Image_preview

No definition for Image_profile_bang

No definition for Image_quantize

No definition for Image_quantum_operator

No definition for Image_radial_blur

No definition for Image_radial_blur_channel

No definition for Image_raise

No definition for Image_random_threshold_channel

No definition for Image_recolor

No definition for Image_reduce_noise

No definition for Image_resize

No definition for Image_resize_bang

No definition for Image_roll

No definition for Image_rotate

No definition for Image_rotate_bang

No definition for Image_sample

No definition for Image_sample_bang

No definition for Image_scale

No definition for Image_scale_bang

No definition for Image_segment

No definition for Image_selective_blur_channel

No definition for Image_separate

No definition for Image_sepiatone

No definition for Image_set_channel_depth

No definition for Image_shade

No definition for Image_shadow

No definition for Image_sharpen

No definition for Image_sharpen_channel

No definition for Image_shave

No definition for Image_shave_bang

No definition for Image_shear

No definition for Image_sigmoidal_contrast_channel

No definition for Image_signature

No definition for Image_sketch

No definition for Image_solarize

No definition for Image_spaceship

No definition for Image_sparse_color

No definition for Image_splice

No definition for Image_spread

No definition for Image_stegano

No definition for Image_stereo

No definition for Image_strip_bang

No definition for Image_store_pixels

No definition for Image_swirl

No definition for Image_sync_profiles

No definition for Image_texture_flood_fill

No definition for Image_threshold

No definition for Image_thumbnail

No definition for Image_thumbnail_bang

No definition for Image_tint

No definition for Image_to_color

No definition for Image_to_blob

No definition for Image_transparent

No definition for Image_transparent_chroma

No definition for Image_transpose

No definition for Image_transpose_bang

No definition for Image_transverse

No definition for Image_transverse_bang

No definition for Image_trim

No definition for Image_trim_bang

No definition for Image_undefine

No definition for Image_unique_colors

No definition for Image_unsharp_mask

No definition for Image_unsharp_mask_channel

No definition for Image_vignette

No definition for Image_watermark

No definition for Image_wave

No definition for Image_wet_floor

No definition for Image_white_threshold

No definition for Image_write

No definition for ImageList_remap

No definition for ImageList_animate

No definition for ImageList_append

No definition for ImageList_average

No definition for ImageList_coalesce

No definition for ImageList_composite_layers

No definition for ImageList_deconstruct

No definition for ImageList_display

No definition for ImageList_flatten_images

No definition for ImageList_fx

No definition for ImageList_map

No definition for ImageList_montage

No definition for ImageList_morph

No definition for ImageList_mosaic

No definition for ImageList_optimize_layers

No definition for ImageList_quantize

No definition for ImageList_to_blob

No definition for ImageList_write

No definition for Draw_annotate

No definition for Draw_clone

No definition for Draw_composite

No definition for Draw_draw

No definition for Draw_dup

No definition for Draw_get_type_metrics

No definition for Draw_get_multiline_type_metrics

No definition for Draw_initialize

No definition for Draw_init_copy

No definition for Draw_inspect

No definition for Draw_marshal_dump

No definition for Draw_marshal_load

No definition for Draw_primitive

No definition for DrawOptions_initialize

No definition for Pixel_from_color

No definition for Pixel_from_HSL

No definition for Pixel_from_hsla

No definition for Pixel_spaceship

No definition for Pixel_case_eq

No definition for Pixel_eql_q

No definition for Pixel_initialize

No definition for Pixel_init_copy

No definition for Pixel_clone

No definition for Pixel_dup

No definition for Pixel_fcmp

No definition for Pixel_hash

No definition for Pixel_intensity

No definition for Pixel_marshal_dump

No definition for Pixel_marshal_load

No definition for Pixel_to_color

No definition for Pixel_to_HSL

No definition for Pixel_to_hsla

No definition for Pixel_to_s

No definition for Montage_initialize

No definition for rm_no_freeze

No definition for Info_initialize

No definition for Info_channel

No definition for rm_no_freeze

No definition for Info_define

No definition for Info_aset

No definition for Info_aref

No definition for Info_undefine

No definition for PolaroidOptions_initialize

No definition for GradientFill_initialize

No definition for GradientFill_fill

No definition for TextureFill_initialize

No definition for TextureFill_fill

No definition for ImageMagickError_initialize

No definition for Enum_initialize

No definition for Enum_to_s

No definition for Enum_to_i

No definition for Enum_spaceship

No definition for Enum_case_eq
/Users/jitscaleusa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/rdoc/rdoc.rb:280: warning: conflicting chdir during another chdir block
/Users/jitscaleusa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/rdoc/rdoc.rb:287: warning: conflicting chdir during another chdir block
Done installing documentation for rmagick after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
```

OK, installed..? Missing alot of definitions. Something is afoot. Let's see if the contents went where I expect them.

```
Elliott:trunk jitscaleusa$ gem contents rmagick
Unable to find gem 'rmagick' in default gem paths

Directories searched:
/Users/jitscaleusa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/specifications
/Users/jitscaleusa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@global/specifications
Elliott:trunk jitscaleusa$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (10.0.3) 
Using Ascii85 (1.0.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.5.0) 
Using activesupport (3.2.11) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.11) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.4) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.2.2) 
Using actionpack (3.2.11) 
Using mime-types (1.19) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.12) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.11) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.35) 
Using activerecord (3.2.11) 
Using activerecord-import (0.3.1) 
Using activeresource (3.2.11) 
Using addressable (2.3.2) 
Using authlogic (3.1.3) 
Using cancan (1.6.8) 
Using highline (1.6.15) 
Using net-ssh (2.6.2) 
Using net-scp (1.0.4) 
Using net-sftp (2.0.5) 
Using net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0) 
Using capistrano (2.13.5) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.3.3) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.7.6) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.16.0) 
Using railties (3.2.11) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using cookiejar (0.3.0) 
Using country-select (1.1.1) 
Using cron-spec (0.1.2) 
Using daemons (1.1.9) 
Using hiredis (0.4.5) 
Using em-hiredis (0.1.1) 
Using eventmachine (1.0.0) 
Using em-socksify (0.2.1) 
Using http_parser.rb (0.5.3) 
Using em-http-request (1.0.3) 
Using fastercsv (1.5.5) 
Using faye-websocket (0.4.6) 
Using yajl-ruby (1.1.0) 
Using faye (0.8.6) 
Using faye-redis (0.1.0) 
Using geokit (1.6.5) 
Using google_visualr (2.1.3) 
Using googlecharts (1.6.8) 
Using haml (3.1.7) 
Using hashery (2.0.1) 
Using jbuilder (0.9.0) 
Using jquery-rails (2.1.2) 
Using libv8 (3.3.10.4) 
Using mustache (0.99.4) 
Using parallel-forkmanager (1.5.1) 
Using ruby-rc4 (0.1.5) 
Using pdf-reader (1.2.0) 
Using pg (0.14.1) 
Using ttfunk (1.0.3) 
Using prawn (0.12.0) 
Using bundler (1.3.1) 
Using rails (3.2.11) 
Using redis (3.0.1) 
Using redis-namespace (1.2.1) 
Using request_store (1.0.5) 
Installing rmagick (2.12.2) 
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Users/jitscaleusa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/rmagick-2.12.2/README.html
An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.12.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.12.2'` succeeds before bundling.
Elliott:trunk jitscaleusa$ sudo gem install rmagick -v '2.12.2'
Password:
Fetching: rmagick-2.12.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/jitscaleusa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for clang... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.3.5... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagickCore... no
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagick... no
Can't install RMagick 2.12.2. Can't find the ImageMagick library or one of the dependent libraries. Check the mkmf.log file for more detailed information.

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/jitscaleusa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/bin/ruby
    --with-MagickCorelib
    --without-MagickCorelib
    --with-Magicklib
    --without-Magicklib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jitscaleusa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/jitscaleusa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.12.2/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
Elliott:trunk jitscaleusa$ mdfind RMagick
/Users/jitscaleusa/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/9abgx4e5.default/sessionstore.js
/opt/local/share/doc/ImageMagick-6.8.0/www/sitemap.html
/opt/local/share/doc/ImageMagick-6.8.0/www/mirrors.html
/opt/local/share/doc/ImageMagick-6.8.0/www/index.html
/opt/local/share/doc/ImageMagick-6.8.0/www/history.html
/opt/local/share/doc/ImageMagick-6.8.0/www/changelog.html
/opt/local/share/doc/ImageMagick-6.8.0/www/api/pixel-view.html
/opt/local/share/doc/ImageMagick-6.8.0/www/api/colorspace.html
/opt/local/share/doc/ImageMagick-6.8.0/www/api.html
/opt/local/share/doc/ImageMagick-6.8.0/www/Magick++/ChangeLog.html
/opt/local/share/doc/ImageMagick-6.8.0/index.html
/opt/local/share/doc/ImageMagick-6.8.0/ChangeLog
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/ruby/rb-rmagick
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/ruby/rb-rmagick/Portfile
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/PortIndex.quick
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/PortIndex
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/PortIndex
/Users/jitscaleusa/guruee/tags/production/Gemfile
/Users/jitscaleusa/guruee/tags/production/Gemfile.lock
/Users/jitscaleusa/guruee/trunk/Gemfile
/Users/jitscaleusa/guruee/trunk/Gemfile.lock
```

Hm. Can't find rmagick that just downloaded, can't bundle. Gyar.

```
Elliott:trunk jitscaleusa$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.0-10 2013-03-03 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2013 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features:  OpenCL
```

Has anyone come across this issue and find a reasonable solution? Thanks ahead of time and apologies if this has been addressed before.

Comment: via jewelry box, yes.

Comment: you shouldn't need sudo for an rvm install should you? Just wondering if it's a clue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like rmagick wasn't finding some of the libraries it needed to. https://coderwall.com/p/wnomjg provides an effective fix to make sure it links correctly. The gem attempted to install, reported that it installed when in fact it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try it ...

```
 brew install imagemagick     
 gem install rmagick
```

[For more info](http://www.codedrop.ca/blog/archives/214)